RAG using Langchain / Chroma - Unable to save more than 99 Records to Database
I'm using the following code to load the content of markdown files (only one file, in my case), split it into chunks and then embed and store the chunks one by one. My file is split into 801 chunks. However, this code is unable to save the embeddings to disk in the vector db.
def load_documents():
loader = DirectoryLoader(DATA_PATH, glob="*.md")

documents = loader.load()

return documents

def split_text(documents: list[Document]):
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(

    chunk_size=300,

    chunk_overlap=100,

    length_function=len,

    add_start_index=True,

)

chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

print(f"Split {len(documents)} documents into {len(chunks)} chunks.")



document = chunks[10]

print(document.page_content)

print(document.metadata)



return chunks

def save_to_chroma(chunks: list[Document]):
# Clear out the database first.

if os.path.exists(CHROMA_PATH):

    shutil.rmtree(CHROMA_PATH)



# Create a new DB from the documents.

db = Chroma.from_documents(

    chunks, OpenAIEmbeddings(), persist_directory=CHROMA_PATH

)

While analysing this problem, I attempted to save the chunks one by one instead, using a for loop:
for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
db = Chroma.from_documents(
chunks, OpenAIEmbeddings(), persist_directory=CHROMA_PATH
)
I found that the code does save up to 99 chunks / embeddings, but always crashes when it tries to save further data. To investigate further, I opened the underlying database using DB Browser for SQLite and saw that Chroma was saving a max of 99 records in the 'embeddings' table. However, I was able to manually add more records to it i.e. exceeding 99.
I also tried a few variations i.e. by:

saving the chunks in batches of 10 or 30
not deleting the existing database already containing 99 records, and then attempting to write more data
playing around with the chunk size and chunk overlap

However, none of the above made any difference.
Does anybody know why this is happening and how to solve this problem?

Seems there is an active Github issue here https://github.com/chroma-core/chroma/issues/2513

Thanks. The issue is indeed similar, though it's related to chromadb whereas I'm using LangChain Chroma.

My problem was solved when I re-installed python on my pc due to some other problem. Now, when I run the code, it works like magic! All the chunks are being saved now regardless of whether I save them all in one go or in batches.
EDIT:
The problem was actually due to a conflict in the installed libraries. It gets resolved when you use a virtual environment, so no need to re-install python.

Please do not roll back edits that improve the post. Any commentary not directly related to the question does not belong there. If you keep rolling back, we'll have to lock the post.

How is the "commentary" not related to the question?
And why won't you let me know why the question was voted down instead of resorting to such high-handed tactics

How is asking about downvotes related to the question? People who find your answer don't care about if or why you got a downvote. They only care about solving their problem. If your answer was useful they may upvote it, if it's not useful they may downvote it. Also please carefully read this post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-it-required-to-provide-comments-feedback-for-downvotes-and-why-are-pr

Hi Just wanted to report I am also experiencing the same issues (on Windows 11). I could not resolve it.
So I had to directly work with chromadb instead of Langchain Chroma. This way, I was able to save beyond 99 records into a persistent db.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
